# What is the usual interval between filming and releasing a movie

Tags: film-industry

I know that at the preseent time it is normal for  movies to have weeks or months of post production work such as editing and sound track and often special effects, and after they are completed they may be kept for some time until the best time to release them.

Thus I expect that most present day movies are released about six mnths to a year or two after being filmed.

And back in the early days of movie making I think that most movies were released only a few weeks or months after being filmed because of less lengthy post production and other factors.

And I think that most filmed tv programs are filmed a few months before being broadcast.

So are my impressions accurate?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Obviously different movies require different amounts of post-production. And different movies follow different schedules. For example, principle photography for Return of the King was shot as part of a gigantic block of filming the trilogy in 1999/2000 - three years before that movie's release).

That said, [someone has crunched the numbers](https://stephenfollows.com/how-long-the-average-hollywood-movie-take-to-make/). The average movie takes 871 days between the studio announcing the project and it hitting the cinemas, with 301 days for post-production (based on 782 live action movies made between 2006 and 2016).

As to how that compares historically? That's proving tricky to find. Obviously very early movies, say 1920s and 1930s, mostly would have had shorter post-production times. My feeling, though, is that by the late 1940s and certainly the 1950s, your typical movie schedule wouldn't be that different, on average.

As a bonus, Wikipedia has a list of [movies with the longest production times](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_with_longest_production_time). Many of these are animations, which naturally take longer than live action, others are indie projects like Peter Jackson's Bad Taste, while others were ambitious/groundbreaking or simply in development hell. Some of these movies are also quite old ones, like Howard Hughes' Hell's Angels.